# How to Get In-Depth SSL Certificate Information

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

How would I go about getting SSL information from a particular website?  Ideally I would like to inspect the entire chain's info, similar to how your browser displays their SSL information.

[image]

[image: In-Depth SSL Information]

I thought you might be able to get this information using the `https` module, however it doesn't appear to return much information about the SSL certificate(s) themselves.

```
request = require('https').request

req = request {
  hostname : 'www.google.com',
  path : '/',
  port : 443,
  method : 'GET'
}, (res) ->
  console.log('Status Code: ' + res.statusCode)
  console.log('Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers, null, '  '))
  process.exit(0)

req.on 'error', (e) ->  throw e
req.end()
```

I know the TLS stuff is set up pre-connecting, so I'm not super-surprised about the response not having much pertinent information.

Where should I start with inspecting a website's SSL certificates?  Maybe I should be using the `tls` module here somehow?

Comment: Not trying to do anything malicious.  The plan was to create something that checks if a cert uses SHA-1 vs SHA-2 due to [its impending deprecation.](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html)

Comment: [Additional useful information.](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17656/how-are-chrome-and-firefox-validating-ssl-certificates)  [Some more.](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6737/what-is-an-ssl-certificate-intended-to-prove-and-how-does-it-do-it)